# No enclosing instance of type Kia is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Kia

Tags: java, abstract

```
package com.abstration.abstractclass;

    abstract class CarTest 
    {
    abstract void start();
    abstract void accelerate();
    abstract void brakes();
    }
    class Kia extends CarTest
    {
    void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Kia started");
    }   
    void accelerate()
    {
        System.out.println("Kia accelerate");
    }
    void brakes()
    {
        System.out.println("kia stops");
    }
    class Audi extends CarTest
    {
        void start()
        {
            System.out.println("Audi started");
        }   
        void accelerate()
        {
            System.out.println("Audi accelerate");
        }
        void brakes()
        {
            System.out.println("Audi stops");
        }
    }


    public static class Driver
    {
        void driver(CarTest c)
        {
            c.start();
            c.accelerate();
            c.brakes();
        }
    }

      public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Driver d = new Driver();
        d.driver(new Kia());
        d.driver(new Audi());
    }


}
```

ERRORS I am facing:-

```
1)No enclosing instance of type Kia is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Kia (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Kia).
```

Comment: Remove the "static" from the Driver class declaration.

Comment: Where are the constructors?

Comment: `}` is missing to close Kia class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file CarTest you should have:

```
abstract class CarTest 
{
abstract void start();
abstract void accelerate();
abstract void brakes();

static class Kia extends CarTest
{
    Kia() {
    }

    void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Kia started");
    }   
    void accelerate()
    {
        System.out.println("Kia accelerate");
    }
    void brakes()
    {
        System.out.println("kia stops");
    }
}

static class Audi extends CarTest
{
    Audi() {
    }

    void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Audi started");
    }   
    void accelerate()
    {
        System.out.println("Audi accelerate");
    }
    void brakes()
    {
        System.out.println("Audi stops");
    }
 }
}
```

Note that Kia and Audi are now static inner classes and have a no-arg constructor.  Next you should put in ANOTHER file, the class Driver that looks like this:

```
class Driver
{
    Driver(){}

    void driver(CarTest c)
    {
        c.start();
        c.accelerate();
        c.brakes();
    }
}
```

And finally in A THIRD file, you put your main class that will call the other classes like this:

```
import (thePackage).CarTest.Audi;
import (thePackage).CarTest.Kia;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Driver d = new Driver();
        d.driver(new Kia());
        d.driver(new Audi());
    }
}
```

It is important to separate your classes into different files and not keep everything into one giant file.  It makes it confusing to read, to fix, and to really do anything.  You also need to make sure to create constructors for classes that will instantiated AKA you will use `new` on them.  Also make sure all of these files are in the same package.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Kia cannot be resolved to a type
 Audi cannot be resolved to a type

 at com.abstration.abstractclass.Test1.main(Test1.java:12)                                                            IN third file the main method file I am getting this error

Comment: You need to import the other classes using an import statement at the top

Comment: @SuNnY SaikuMaR I edited the code with an example of what I mean, change `(thePackage)` to whatever package they are in.

Comment: Also make sure the main method is inside of a class in the third file, it cannot just be by itself.

Comment: Done got output. Thanks for helping Nexevis

Comment: @SuNnY SaikuMaR  Mark answer as completed if it worked, thanks